# Docker command difference

Tags: docker

I am new to docker container. Can someone please tell me what is difference between these two commands. In my knowledge, have the same out put than why we use the bash command.

```
docker run -it ubuntu 
docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

Comment: `docker run -it ubuntu` run whatever `CMD` defined in the image, the other one overwrite the command to `bash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker run -it ubuntu` let's you run command inside the container.

The `bash` is the command to run.

For example instead you can run

```
docker run -it ubuntu ls /home
```

This will list the `/home` dir inside the container.

Answer (score 1):

In docker, we run a linux container. As you know, a linux system is alive when it's init 0 service is alive. 'init 0' is kind of the heart of a linux system. when 'init 0' is killed, the linux system also dies.

In a containerized architecture, you run a container for simply one purpose i.e. to simply run one service.  we want if the service fails, the container also dies. so we define the servcie as `init 0` job for the container.

when you run `docker run -it ubuntu bash`, here, `bash` is the init 0 job for the container. As soon as you exit from bash, the container stops working.

Instead of using `bash` you can also try another commands like @Shmuel suggested.

Well, when we create custom images, often we want to pre-define default 'init 0' job for our custom image. If the init 0' is predefined, you don't need to mention it in `docker run` command.

In ubuntu image, the pre-defined 'init 0' job is `bash`. So, if you don't mention `bash` in the `run` command, it works the same.